# Need help in identifying controls on Light box using webdriver and java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, lightbox

I am trying to automate the sign in flow of a web site. When I click sign in, a lightbox pop up comes and my script does not identify the elements inside the pop up. The site is www.zillow.com and this happens when I click on Sign In link on top right corner.

I tried using the JavascriptExecutor, waits and few more methods but could not identify. Need help here.Thanks !! The error I get it as follows.

```
public class Trial {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.zillow.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_opener']/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcde");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']']")).sendKeys("abcde");
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='email']"}
Command duration or timeout: 20.51 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'pc-linux-ravip', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-65-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='email']}
Session ID: 3b861869-4a8b-4cd1-b051-bab213d02077
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=41.0.1}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:358)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at com.trials.testng.learning.Trial.main(Trial.java:18)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='email']"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'pc-linux-ravip', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-65-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///tmp/anonymous4582481678202576888webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10667)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///tmp/anonymous4582481678202576888webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:623)
```

Comment: Please post code showing what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Andy....thanks for your reply ... my code is as below.                                        
public class Trial {
 
 public static void main(String [] args){
  
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.zillow.com");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_opener']/span")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcde");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']']")).sendKeys("abcde");
 }
}

Comment: Please post code *in your question*, *formatted as code*. It is impossible to read in comments.

Comment: public class Trial {
public static void main(String [] args){
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.zillow.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_opener']/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcde");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='password']']")).sendKeys("abcde");
 }
}

Comment: That is a comment again. Please edit your question to add your code.

Comment: I am formatting this and posting but when I submit, it changes the format ... I am sorry I am new to this.

Comment: hi ... can anyone help me here please ....

Comment: Is it in iframe? if so you need to switch to it before accessing those elements. driver.switchTo().frame(index/name/locator);

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your Xpath is in wrong format. I modified your code little bit and it worked fine

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://www.zillow.com");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sign in')]")).click();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcde");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("abcde");
```

I have changed following xpath and introduced one `implicit-wait` after clicking Sign In button

1. `//span[contains(text(),'Sign in')]` to identify sign in button.
2. `//input[@id='email']` to identify email text box
3. `//input[@id='password']` to identify password text box

Comment: Thanks Deepak. But //* or //input works the same way. Also it did not work for me. I observed something, sometime the pop up comes up on clicking on Sign in and sometimes a page. When the page comes, it works fine (my code and your code) but when you run it for 2nd or 3rd time and when pop up comes, the code fails.

Comment: you can try adding Explicit wait after clicking on sign in button. 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")));
even i ran the same code more than three times it works fine. 
If still error exists can you add screen shot.

Comment: thanks for your time on this ...It is throwing the same exception that I have posted in this question ... sorry I am not able to post here as a part of the comment due to character constraints ....I tried your suggestion given above but still fails.

Comment: Actually i found the solution. I will post it in another Answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually that popup is in frames and that particular frame doesn't have id or name on it.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://www.zillow.com");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sign in')]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                List<WebElement> iframeElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
                System.out.println("The total number of iframes are " + iframeElements.size());
                for(int i=0;i<iframeElements.size();i++)
                {
                try
                {
                System.out.println("Entered Try");
                driver.switchTo().frame(i);
                System.out.println("Switched to frame");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcde");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("abcde");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                System.out.println("Not in this frame:"+ i);
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }
                System.out.println("Out of catch");
                }
```

I getting all frames from the webpage and saving it in `List<WebElement>` and using for loop to navigate.

By using the frame Index , i'm handling the frame i.e. `driver.switchTo().frame(i);` i is index

Comment: Hey Deepak .... that's awesome .. its working perfectly fine now .... Thanks for your help and great inputs ...Kudos to you.